# Rank records in sets based on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
╔════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║      ENDTIME       ║ TRAILERID ║ POSITION ║ STORE ║ STOP ║
╠════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 11/7/2017 15:15:44 ║       145 ║ L1       ║ BOS   ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:16:57 ║       145 ║ L2       ║ NY    ║    3 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:17:24 ║       145 ║ R1       ║ NY    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:17:57 ║       145 ║ R2       ║ NY    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:18:26 ║       145 ║ L3       ║ CT    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:34:24 ║       145 ║ R3       ║ CT    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:02:01 ║       999 ║ L1       ║ NJ    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:22:33 ║       999 ║ R1       ║ NJ    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:23:14 ║       999 ║ L2       ║ WA    ║    3 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:27:16 ║       999 ║ R2       ║ WA    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:27:46 ║       999 ║ L3       ║ WA    ║    1 ║
╚════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

I'm trying to change the stop field to look like below

```
╔════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║      ENDTIME       ║ TRAILERID ║ POSITION ║ STORE ║ STOP ║
╠════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 11/7/2017 15:15:44 ║       145 ║ L1       ║ BOS   ║    3 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:16:57 ║       145 ║ L2       ║ NY    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:17:24 ║       145 ║ R1       ║ NY    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:17:57 ║       145 ║ R2       ║ NY    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:18:26 ║       145 ║ L3       ║ CT    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 15:34:24 ║       145 ║ R3       ║ CT    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:02:01 ║       999 ║ L1       ║ NJ    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:22:33 ║       999 ║ R1       ║ NJ    ║    2 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:23:14 ║       999 ║ L2       ║ WA    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:27:16 ║       999 ║ R2       ║ WA    ║    1 ║
║ 11/7/2017 16:27:46 ║       999 ║ L3       ║ WA    ║    1 ║
╚════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

my attempt was to use row_number and rank but I cant' get to get the right results. Is giving me the first table result.

```
SELECT ps.ENDTIME, ps.TRUCKID as TRAILERID, ps.CONTAINERPOSITION as POSITION,ps.STORE,RANK() OVER( PARTITION by ps.STORE  ORDER BY ps.ENDTIME DESC)AS STOP 
FROM TRAILERDATA ps
ORDER BY ps.ENDTIME ASC
```

The most important thing is to label by group of stores with the same rank even if the ENDTIME is not in proper sequence.

Comment: What's the value of StopNum?

Comment: Sorry. STOPNUM is STORE. I’ll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
    (EndTime datetime2(0), TrailerID int, Position varchar(50), Store varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @T (EndTime, TrailerID, Position, Store) VALUES
('2017-11-07 15:15:44',145,'L1','BOS'),
('2017-11-07 15:16:57',145,'L2','NY'),
('2017-11-07 15:17:24',145,'R1','NY'),
('2017-11-07 15:17:57',145,'R2','NY'),
('2017-11-07 15:18:26',145,'L3','CT'),
('2017-11-07 15:34:24',145,'R3','CT'),
('2017-11-07 16:02:01',999,'L1','NJ'),
('2017-11-07 16:22:33',999,'R1','NJ'),
('2017-11-07 16:23:14',999,'L2','WA'),
('2017-11-07 16:27:16',999,'R2','WA'),
('2017-11-07 16:27:46',999,'L3','WA');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        EndTime, TrailerID, Position, Store
        ,MAX(EndTime) OVER (PARTITION BY TrailerID, Store) AS SortingTime
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    EndTime, TrailerID, Position, Store
    ,SortingTime
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TrailerID ORDER BY SortingTime DESC) AS Stop
FROM CTE
ORDER BY TrailerID, Stop DESC, EndTime;
```

**Result**

```
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+------+
|       EndTime       | TrailerID | Position | Store |     SortingTime     | Stop |
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 2017-11-07 15:15:44 |       145 | L1       | BOS   | 2017-11-07 15:15:44 |    3 |
| 2017-11-07 15:16:57 |       145 | L2       | NY    | 2017-11-07 15:17:57 |    2 |
| 2017-11-07 15:17:24 |       145 | R1       | NY    | 2017-11-07 15:17:57 |    2 |
| 2017-11-07 15:17:57 |       145 | R2       | NY    | 2017-11-07 15:17:57 |    2 |
| 2017-11-07 15:18:26 |       145 | L3       | CT    | 2017-11-07 15:34:24 |    1 |
| 2017-11-07 15:34:24 |       145 | R3       | CT    | 2017-11-07 15:34:24 |    1 |
| 2017-11-07 16:02:01 |       999 | L1       | NJ    | 2017-11-07 16:22:33 |    2 |
| 2017-11-07 16:22:33 |       999 | R1       | NJ    | 2017-11-07 16:22:33 |    2 |
| 2017-11-07 16:23:14 |       999 | L2       | WA    | 2017-11-07 16:27:46 |    1 |
| 2017-11-07 16:27:16 |       999 | R2       | WA    | 2017-11-07 16:27:46 |    1 |
| 2017-11-07 16:27:46 |       999 | L3       | WA    | 2017-11-07 16:27:46 |    1 |
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+------+
```

In the result you can see how `SortingTime` allows to calculate `DENSE_RANK` that you need. Essentially, `SortingTime` defines grouping by `TrailerID` and `Store` and also conveniently provides a way to sort by.

---

The query above relies on `EndTime` being different for different `Stores`. More specifically, the MAX time being different. If you have two `Stores` with the same maximum `EndTime`, the query would assign the same `Stop` for them.

If this is the possibility, then add `Store` to the `ORDER BY`:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        EndTime, TrailerID, Position, Store
        ,MAX(EndTime) OVER (PARTITION BY TrailerID, Store) AS SortingTime
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    EndTime, TrailerID, Position, Store
    ,SortingTime
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TrailerID ORDER BY SortingTime DESC, Store) AS Stop
FROM CTE
ORDER BY TrailerID, Stop DESC, EndTime;
```

Comment: Very smart. I think this should work. Thanks for taking your time and for making me looking into dense_rank.